# How to integrate Maven 1.0 in Java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i have to rebuilt a maven 1.0 webapplication in Java. However i can not get the application to run in Eclipse IDE.

I already installed Eclipse Luna 4.4 EE including JDK 1.7. 
Maven 1.0 was installed succesfully via cmd .bat file. 
As Server for the application Tomcat 7 is used.
What do i have to do to migrate the project properly into eclipse.
Any help woulde be much appreciated.

The Problem occured to me is when i tried to import the project as existing maven project it doesnot regconize it as a maven project. And the import stays dead.

Comment: Why Eclipse though? Build using Maven.

Comment: The application was built this way and contains some custom JavaCode and servlets

Comment: Have you tried to build it with a new Maven, like 3.6.0?

Comment: The issue is simply cause Maven 1.0 uses a different POM Module (3.0.0) which is (I suppose so) not supported by M2E in Eclipse...So I have my doubts that this will every run inside Eclipse just use the command line ...and I strongly recommend to migrate that to Maven 3.6.0...

Answer (score 1):

Maven Eclipse plugin installation step by step:

Open Eclipse IDE
Click Help -> Install New Software...
Click Add button at top right corner
At pop up: fill up Name as "M2Eclipse" and Location as "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases" or http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.0

Now click OK

After that installation would be started.

Another way to install Maven plug-in for Eclipse:

Open Eclipse
Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
Search by Maven
Click "Install" button at "Maven Integration for Eclipse" section
Follow the instruction step by step
After successful installation do the followings in Eclipse:

Go to Window --> Preferences
Observe, Maven is enlisted at left panel
Finally,

Click on an existing project
Select Configure -> Convert to Maven Project

Now you can import project.

Comment: Since i installed Luna EE it already contains the maven plugin

Answer (score 0):

From command line if you have maven in your system variables, you can do 
`mvn eclipse:eclipse` in your project path.

If not works, you can follow this guide:
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/no-more-mvn-eclipseeclipse-whats-next/